# Bulk Copy Conditional Formatting to other ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have multiple conditional formatting rules applied to a range with custom formulas and specific colors. I need to copy and apply those rules to the other 24 ranges in the same sheet.

The thing is that even after copying the rules to other ranges, I'd still need to edit each formula depending on its position in the cells to reference. But I know that can't be achieved automatically, so I just want to take those rules and put them into other ranges, and then edit each formula manually. That would still save some time.

I tried to create a script with the help of ChatGPT, but the code it gave me kept returning errors.

Here are the data details:

The range that contains custom rules: `B14:H19`

Ranges that I want to apply the rules to:

`K14:Q19
T14:Z19
AC14:AI19
AL14:AR19
AB23:H28
K23:Q28
T23:Z28
AC23:AI28
AL23:AR28
B32:H37
K32:Q37
T32:Z37
AC32:AI37
AL32:AR37
B41:H46
K41:Q46
T41:Z46
AC41:AI46
AL41:AR46
B50:H55
K50:Q55
T50:Z55
AC50:AI55
AL50:AR55`

Here's the code suggested by ChatGPT but it didn't work:

```
 function copyConditionalFormatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rangesToApply = [
    // Replace with the ranges where you want to apply the conditional formatting
    sheet.getRange("K14:Q19"),
    sheet.getRange("T14:Z19"),
    sheet.getRange("AC14:AI19"),
    sheet.getRange("AL14:AR19"),
    sheet.getRange("AB23:H28"),
    sheet.getRange("K23:Q28"),
    sheet.getRange("T23:Z28"),
    sheet.getRange("AC23:AI28"),
    sheet.getRange("AL23:AR28"),
    sheet.getRange("B32:H37"),
    sheet.getRange("K32:Q37"),
    sheet.getRange("T32:Z37"),
    sheet.getRange("AC32:AI37"),
    sheet.getRange("AL32:AR37"),
    sheet.getRange("B41:H46"),
    sheet.getRange("K41:Q46"),
    sheet.getRange("T41:Z46"),
    sheet.getRange("AC41:AI46"),
    sheet.getRange("AL41:AR46"),
    sheet.getRange("B50:H55"),
    sheet.getRange("K50:Q55"),
    sheet.getRange("T50:Z55"),
    sheet.getRange("AC50:AI55"),
    sheet.getRange("AL50:AR55")
  ];
  // Loop through each range and apply the conditional formatting
  for (var i = 0; i < rangesToApply.length; i++) {
    var newRange = rangesToApply[i];
    var rules = range1.getConditionalFormatRules();
    newRange.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
  }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
TypeError: newRange.setConditionalFormatRules is not a function
copyConditionalFormatting   @ Code.gs:39
```

I'm not sure If I can share a Demo of this, because it's connected to other sheets and the conditional formatting rules don't copy with data. So here's screenshot of the custom formulas in Formatting rules (there's 15 rules).

[image]

I hope someone would be able to help me here.

[DEMO LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1401i5GvZczoKw-jySDbv3O8t6bPjUIFv5bjENop1jmE/edit?usp=sharing)

P.S: please note that you'll see N/A errors in cells because that sheet is part of a more extensive system and linked to other sheets that I can't share.

Comment: Unfortunately, from `it didn't work:`, I cannot understand your current issue. I apologize for this. But, when I saw your script, it seems that `range1` is not declared. Is this related to your current issue? By the way, unfortunately, the methods of `getConditionalFormatRules` and `setConditionalFormatRules` are not for Class Range. Those are for Class Sheet. This is another issue. By the way, about `so I just want to take those rules and put them into other ranges, and then edit each formula manually.`, in your question, you can ignore the formula. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thanks for your input!

I provided the code error that I was prompted with. I'm not really into coding, so I don't have extensive knowledge about those classes in the generated code.

I want at least to copy the exact custom formulas in those rules. Then I'll change their parameters manually.

Please check again the post, I've added a screenshot of how the Formatting rules look like.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. I cannot understand your input and output situations. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: As additional information, I think that the reason for your current error of `newRange.setConditionalFormatRules is not a function` is that the methods of `getConditionalFormatRules` and `setConditionalFormatRules` are not for Class Range, and those are for Class Sheet. Although, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question, how about modifying about this in your script?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. In short, here's what I want:

I have some custom rules in the range B14:H19 (check the screenshot in the post) and I want to copy all those rules and paste in other ranges (check the post for the list of ranges).

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I have some custom rules in the range B14:H19 (check the screenshot in the post) and I want to copy all those rules and paste in other ranges (check the post for the list of ranges)`, where can I see the custom rules of "B14:H19"? I couldn't find it. I apologize for this.

Comment: Please check at the end of the post, you'll find a Demo link that contains conditional formatting rules in the range B10:B15

P.S: please note that you'll see N/A errors in cells because that sheet is part of a more extensive system and linked to other sheets that I can't share.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `you'll find a Demo link that contains conditional formatting rules in the range B10:B15`, what do you want to do with "B10:B15"?

Comment: I want to copy the conditional formatting rules in that range and paste them in other ranges.

Comment: My question was crystal clear and I repeated it multiple times in this thread. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `My question was crystal clear and I repeated it multiple times in this thread.`, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that worked for me:

```
    function copyConditionalFormattingRules() {
  // Define the spreadsheet and sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // Define the source range from which to copy the rules
  var sourceRange = 'B17:H22';

  // Define the target ranges to which to apply the rules
  var targetRanges = [
    'AC17:AI22',
    'AL17:AR22',
    'AB26:H31',
    'K26:Q31',
    'T26:Z31',
    'AC26:AI31',
    'AL26:AR31',
    'B35:H40',
    'K35:Q40',
    'T35:Z40',
    'AC35:AI40',
    'AL35:AR40',
    'B44:H49',
    'K44:Q49',
    'T44:Z49',
    'AC44:AI49',
    'AL44:AR49',
    'B53:H58',
    'K53:Q58',
    'T53:Z58',
    'AC53:AI58',
    'AL53:AR58'
  ];

  // Get the conditional formatting rules from the source range
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  var sourceRules = rules.filter(rule => rule.getRanges().some(range => range.getA1Notation() === sourceRange));

  // Apply the rules to each of the target ranges
  for (var i = 0; i < targetRanges.length; i++) {
    var targetRange = sheet.getRange(targetRanges[i]);

    sourceRules.forEach(rule => {
      var newRule = rule.copy();
      newRule.setRanges([targetRange]);
      rules.push(newRule);
    });
  }

  // Update the sheet with the new rules
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

It copied all the custom rules from the source range and pasted them into the other ranges, and of course, I had to edit the formulas manually, but even though, it saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the methods `getConditionalFormatRules()` and `setConditionalFormatRules()` are not for Class Range.

The `getConditionalFormatRules()` method retrieves all the rules from the whole sheet. To retrieve the rule from a specific range then you have to iterate each rule and retrieve the one that matches with the range you want, in this case you want to copy the rule from range `B10:B15`.

Just to give you an example, I have this script that worked for me. Make sure to add the ID of your spreadsheet in the `spreadSheet` variable and list all the ranges in the `a1Notations` variable.

```
function copyConditionalFormat() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX");
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Monthly Calendar");

  //Get all Sheet rules and iterate through them
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  var newRules = [];
  newRules = newRules.concat(rules);

  //List of the ranges where you want to apply the conditional format rule
  var a1Notations = ["AC10:AI15", "AC19:AI24", "AL10:AR15", "AL19:AR24"];  

  for (let i = 0 ; i < rules.length; i++){
    var ranges = rules[i].getRanges();
    var booleanCondition = rules[i].getBooleanCondition();

    for (let j = 0; j < ranges.length; j++) {
      if(ranges[j].getA1Notation() == "B10:H15"){
        for (let k = 0; k<a1Notations.length; k++){
          var newRule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .withCriteria(booleanCondition.getCriteriaType(), booleanCondition.getCriteriaValues())
          .setBackground(booleanCondition.getBackground())
          .setRanges([sheet.getRange(a1Notations[k])])
          .build();
          newRules.push(newRule)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(newRules)
}
```

Then you will have to edit each formula as it seems it can't be done automatically.

## References:

- [Class ConditionalFormatRule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule)
- [Class ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#setRanges(Range))

Comment: Thank you Lorena, for your suggested solution. I finally got it to work and provided the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder Fernando. I've upvoted Lorena's answer.